# How to restrict access to routes with KeyCloak

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I am building s spring boot app that will use KeyCloak for auth.
I know how to make keycloak restrict full route (for example [https://server.com/product/{id}](https://server.com/product/%7Bid%7D))
but I don't know how to restrict it by the ID in the example such that user1 has only access to /product/1 and user2 has only access to /product/2. Can someone please explain how can I achieve such thing or can someone please point me to some tutorial/article that would help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Spring Security inside your Spring Boot app.  It sounds like what you are describing is:

**11.6. Domain Object Security (ACLs)**

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#domain-acls

Here is a demo using and older version of Spring Boot
https://github.com/maurofokker/spring-security-acl-demo